# $f:D(0,1)\to \mathbb{C}$ , $e^{f(z)}$ is constant $\Rightarrow f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:D(0,1)\to \mathbb{C}$ continuous and $e^{f(z)}$ is constant $\forall z\in D(0,1)$ show $f$ is constant.

---

$\cdot $  $e^f=c=e^{x_0+iy_0}$  and $c\neq 0$

$\Rightarrow f-(x_0+iy_0)=k(z)2\pi i$, where because $k(z)$ is continuous and $D(0,1) $ connected $k(z)=k$ some constant. From that we get $\text{Re}f=x_0$ is constant. And also $\text{Im}f=iy_0+k(z)2\pi i$, but we show that $k(z)=k$ some constant. Thus, $f$ is constant.

Is there a different way to show this ? It came natural  to me that I should use  Cayley transform for some reason, but I couldn't do it.

Comment: I have deleted my answer because I misread the question. It is tagged with [complex-analysis] therefore I had assumed that $f$ is holomorphic.

Comment: Your argument is fine, and is exactly how I would argue for continuous functions $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\exp$ is $2\pi i$-periodic, i.e.

$$\exp a = \exp b \qquad\Longleftrightarrow\qquad a-b\in 2\pi i \Bbb Z$$
That it's actually an equivalence — that is there are no other solutions — can be seen by Euler's identity
$$\exp (x+iy) = e^x(\cos y + i\sin y)$$

For a function $f$ like in the clain this means that $f(z) = f(0)+2\pi i k(z)$ where $k: \Bbb C \to \Bbb Z$ is some integer-valued function.

Now take some $z\in D(0,1)$.  As $D(0,1)$ is path-connected, there is some path $C:[0,1]\to D(0,1)$ with $C(0)=0$ and $C(1) = z$.  This is a continuous curve that connects $0$ with $z$. As $C$ and $f$ are continuous, $f\circ C$ is continuous, too.  This implies $k\circ C$ is continuous with $k(0) = 0$. As the domain of $k$ is $\Bbb Z$, the only way to have $k$ continuous is to have $k(C(t)) = 0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$, which in turn means that $f(z) = f(0)$ for any $z$.  Hence, $f$ is constant.

Note: All we need from $D(0,1)$ is that it is path-connected.